# Jquery animation: fade in element, fade out, then stop

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm new to Jquery animation.
I have two elements to fade in, the sequence needs to be like this:
On load, element 1 visible. Fade out after 5 seconds.
Fade in element 2, stop (element 2 remains visible on screen from then on).
At the moment, it works but loops continuously.
Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.no-js').removeClass('no-js'); /* JS is enabled */
  var currentContent = 0;
  var nbContent = $('.content').length;
  var tempo;
  $('.content').eq(currentContent).removeClass('off').addClass('on');

  function changeContent() {
    currentContent++;
    if (currentContent < nbContent) {
      $('.on').toggleClass('off').toggleClass('on');
      $('.off').eq(currentContent).toggleClass('off').toggleClass('on');
    } else {
      currentContent = 0;
      $('.on').toggleClass('off').toggleClass('on');
      $('.off').eq(currentContent).toggleClass('off').toggleClass('on');
    }
  }
  tempo = setInterval(changeContent, 5000);
});
```

```css
.container-content {
  padding: 190px 0 0 6px;
  width: 90%;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

.container-content p {
  margin: 3px 0 0;
}

#content-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 2px;
}

#content-2 .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: -20px;
}

.on {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 2s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  z-index: 2
}

.off {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container-content" class="container-content no-js">
  <div id="content-1" class="content off">
    <p> Some text here
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content-2" class="content off">
    <p> More text here
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: *it works continuously* - the first guess (without looking too closely) would be that you should change `setInterval` to `setTimeout` so it only runs once.

Comment: A closer look and it appears you're expecting more than 2 elements so want to keep updating them.  If you want it to stop at the end then either add `clearTimeout(tempo)` inside the `} else {` or call setTimeout from inside the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Changing setInterval for setTimeout worked perfectly, thanks @freedom-mn!